# Trying to catch an HTTP 401 using Dojo

Tags: javascript, http, dojo

When communicating with a server using Dojo, is it possible to capture a 401 status code before the browser intercepts it?

I'm using Dojo 1.8 to communicate with a RESTful server that uses basic authentication over SSL. The client captures the client's username and password, then includes them in a request to the server as so:

```
request.get(this.url, {
  handleAs: "json",
  user: creds.username,
  password: creds.password
}).then(
  function(user) {
    console.log("user", user);
  },
  function(error) {
    console.log("error", error);
  });
```

When the client credentials are correct, this works OK. But if the credentials are wrong, the browser intercepts the returned 401 status code before my error function gets it.

I've seen other discussions about this issue, including a workaround where the server returns something other than a 401 upon authentication error. Before I go down that route, however, I'd like to know if there is way to cause my code to get the 401 status before the browser.

Alternatively, would using something other than basic auth over SSL make this easier?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't find a way to stop the browser from intercepting a 401 status code, but I worked around it. Here is what I did in case someone else lands on this question. This only works if you have control over what the server returns when authentication is needed.

First I had the server return a 400 status code when authentication is needed. I am using Apache Shiro, so this just involved creating a subclass of BasicHttpAuthenticationFilter and overriding sendChallenge() as so:

```
protected boolean sendChallenge(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response) {
  HttpServletResponse httpResponse = WebUtils.toHttp(response);
  httpResponse.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_BAD_REQUEST);
  String authcHeader = getAuthcScheme() + " realm=\"" + getApplicationName() + "\"";
  httpResponse.setHeader(AUTHENTICATE_HEADER, authcHeader);
  return false;
}
```

In my case I did not want a logout to redirect to a JSP page, so I subclassed Shiro's LogoutFilter preHandle() method as so:

```
protected boolean preHandle(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response) throws Exception {
  Subject subject = getSubject(request, response);
  try {
    subject.logout();
  }
  catch (SessionException ise) {
    // Log exception
  }
  return false;
}
```

I then added the filters to my shiro.ini file:

```
[main]
myAuth = com.example.filters.MyBasicAuthFilter
noRedirectLogout = com.example.filters.NoRedirectLogoutFilter

[urls]
/protected/** = myAuth
/logout = noRedirectLogout
```

You can use a different status code, just make sure to check for the same one on the client.

Next I created a LoginController to handle login and logout:

```
define([], function() {
  var string = {};    
  string.getBytes = function(str) {
    console.log("string.getBytes:str", str);
    var bytes = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < str.length; ++i) {
      bytes.push(str.charCodeAt(i));
    }
    return bytes;
  };
  return string;
});

...

_authorize: function(url, username, password) {
  var namepw = new String(username + ":" + password);
  var authstr = "Basic " + base64.encode(utilString.getBytes(namepw));

  var def = new Deferred();
  request.get(url, {
    handleAs: "json",
    headers : {
      Authorization: authstr
    }
  }).then(
    function(data) {
      def.resolve(data);
    },
    function(err) {
      if (err.response.status == 400) {
        def.progress();
      }
      else {
        def.reject(err);
      }
    });
  return def;
},

login: function(url, user, passwd) {
  return this._authorize(url, user, passwd);
},

logout: function(url) {
  return this._authorize(url, "#fakeuser#", "#fakepw#");
};
```

The code that uses the controller to log in gets back a Deferred, and can do the appropriate thing:

```
var auth = this.controller.login(creds);
Deferred.when(auth,
  function(data) {
    if (data != null) {
      // Successful login
    }
    else {
      // Non-authentication error
    }
  },
  function(err) {
    // Non-authentication error
  },
  function(updt) {
    // Invalid username or password
  }
);
```

The code that invokes a logout also gets back a Deferred:

```
controller.logout("/logout").then(function(val) {
  // Successful logut
}, function(err) {
  // Error attempting to logout
});
```

The logout works by having the logout filter return success (status == 200) regardless of the username password, and passing an invalid username and password that the browser will catch. Hope all this helps someone.